# Como permitir inserir apenas determinada quantidade de registros no sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada `Hoteis` que está relacionada com uma outra tabela auxilar `Hoteis_Fotos`, como o próprio nome sugere essa tabela irá guardar as fotos de determinado hotel. Como devem ter entendido cada hotel pode possuir mais de uma foto, só que no máximo 10 fotos por hotel.

Supondo que a estrutura da minha tabela `Hoteis_Fotos` seja a seguinte:

`create table Hoteis_Fotos(
     id_hotel_foto int not null primary key identity,
     fk_hotel int not null, -- faz referência ao id do hotel na tabela 'Hoteis'
     foto varbinary(max)
)`

Como eu faço para adicionar uma restrição(ou algo do tipo) que possibilite a inserção de apenas 10 fotos por hotel na tabela `Hoteis_Fotos` ?

Comment: Eu faria por trigger -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930286/set-limit-for-a-table-rows-in-sql

Comment: Essa validação precisa mesmo ser via banco?

Comment: @Motta não estava por dentro de como utilizar o rollback e os outros tipos de transações, achei interessante.

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves não necessariamente, mas evitaria ter que fazer outra consulta em tempo de execução(na aplicação) para verificar se determinado hotel já contêm as 10 imagens ou não, pelo menos se não fosse feito no banco a única maneira que eu pensei foi essa. Você teria outra sugestão ?

Comment: Eu sugeriria fazer a consulta. 
Evitar um `select count(*)`, filtrado pela PK (que tem index), pensando em performance é como comprar leite R$ 0,02 mais barato pensando em economizar pra comprar uma casa.

Comment: uma coluna em "hoteis" qtd_fotos , a trigger de insert ou delete em "hoteis_fotos" , somaria ou diminuiria 1 ao campo , se há estiver com 10 barra , pode ser uma solução mais simples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma `TRIGGER` que irá verificar a quantidade atual de registros na tabela `hoteis_fotos` e caso identifique que já há 10 registros, irá causar uma erro com a mensagem de que o número de registros foi excedido:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tr_hoteis_fotos_i', 'TR') IS NULL
BEGIN
  EXEC('CREATE TRIGGER tr_hoteis_fotos_i ON hoteis_fotos INSTEAD OF INSERT AS BEGIN END;');
END;
GO

ALTER TRIGGER tr_hoteis_fotos_i
ON hoteis_fotos
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @fk_hotel      INT,
          @foto          VARBINARY(MAX);

  DECLARE cursor_fotos CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT ins.fk_hotel,
           ins.foto
      FROM inserted ins
  OPEN cursor_fotos;
  FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_fotos
  INTO @fk_hotel,
       @foto;
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @quantidade INT,
            @mensagem   VARCHAR(1000);

    SELECT @quantidade = COUNT(1)
      FROM hoteis_fotos hf WITH(NOLOCK)
     WHERE hf.fk_hotel = @fk_hotel;

    IF @quantidade >= 3
    BEGIN
      SET @mensagem = 'Quantidade de registros excedida para o hotel de código ' + CAST(@fk_hotel AS VARCHAR);
      RAISERROR(@mensagem ,16, 1);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO hoteis_fotos(fk_hotel,
                               foto)
      VALUES(@fk_hotel,
             @foto);
    END;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_fotos   
    INTO @fk_hotel,
         @foto;
  END;
  CLOSE cursor_fotos;  
  DEALLOCATE cursor_fotos;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Neste caso por qual motivo há a necessidade de utilizar o cursor para fazer o `select` em `inserted` ?

Comment: @LoneTonberry para o caso de `INSERT` em lote.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde,

Crie as tabelas abaixo:

```
create table Hoteis
(
  id_hotel int not null primary key identity
);

create table Hoteis_Fotos(
   id_hotel_foto int not null primary key identity,
   fk_hotel int not null,
   foto varbinary(max),
   foreign key(fk_hotel) references Hoteis(id_hotel)
);
```

Após criar, crie uma *stored procedure* para que o próprio banco de dados execute
a tarefa de validação, caso seja direto no banco de dados, se for no .Net (C#, VB), armazenar uma variavel que realize a consulta na base de dados (Ado.Net) com comando:

```
select count(*) from Hoteis_Fotos where fk_hotel = valor informado;
```

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição para ajudá-lo

Comment: Olá Anderson, poderia editar a sua resposta, colocando a implementação de como ficaria o código da `stored procedure`, para que eu possa ter uma ideia de como você pensou que seria feita a validação ?